# SQL to display 0 in the counts

Tags: sql

I have written the below query. However I am not able to get 0 in the corresponding counts. Can you please let me know how can i do join in this query to display 0's?

```
SELECT  b.collected     AS Last_Week_Collected,    
        a.collected     AS THIS_Week_Collected,   
        b.errored       AS Last_Week_Errored,   
        a.errored       AS THIS_Week_Errored,   
        b.processed     AS Last_Week_Processed,   
        a.processed     AS THIS_Week_Processed    
FROM    (
            SELECT stream_id,collected, errored, processed 
            FROM processing_Stats_Archive 
            WHERE stream_id = '29'  
            AND HR_OF_DAY ='5'  
            AND TO_CHAR(batch_Creation_date,'DD-MON-YY')= '03-09-2015'  
        ) a ,  
        (
            SELECT stream_id,collected,errored ,processed  
            FROM processing_Stats_Archive  
            WHERE stream_id = '29'  
            AND HR_OF_DAY ='5' 
            AND TO_CHAR(batch_Creation_date,'DD-MON-YY')= '27-08-2015'  
        ) b   
WHERE   a.stream_id=b.stream_id;
```

Comment: Please try to format your query.

Comment: unable to understand your que.

Comment: You probably want a [`FULL JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) rather than the implicit inner join you have written. Then you would just use `COALESCE` to change your `NULL` missing results to 0.

Comment: Can you please help me for doing this??

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your syntax, it looks like you are using a `Oracle` database. So, the `NVL` function should work for you just fine. Also, since you want to return `0`'s in place of null values, instead of `inner join`, you would want to do some form of `outer join` (either left, right, or full depending on your needs). If you want to return all the rows from both queries, you will need to use `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead like this:

```
SELECT nvl(b.collected, 0) AS Last_Week_Collected
    ,nvl(a.collected, 0) AS THIS_Week_Collected
    ,nvl(b.errored, 0) AS Last_Week_Errored
    ,nvl(a.errored, 0) AS THIS_Week_Errored
    ,nvl(b.processed, 0) AS Last_Week_Processed
    ,nvl(a.processed, 0) AS THIS_Week_Processed
FROM (
    SELECT stream_id
        ,collected
        ,errored
        ,processed
    FROM processing_Stats_Archive
    WHERE stream_id = '29'
        AND HR_OF_DAY = '5'
        AND TO_CHAR(batch_Creation_date, 'DD-MON-YY') = '03-09-2015'
    ) a
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT stream_id
        ,collected
        ,errored
        ,processed
    FROM processing_Stats_Archive
    WHERE stream_id = '29'
        AND HR_OF_DAY = '5'
        AND TO_CHAR(batch_Creation_date, 'DD-MON-YY') = '27-08-2015'
    ) b ON a.stream_id = b.stream_id;
```

Comment: Not working where there are no rows for specified dates, Full outer join doesn't help

Comment: It worked fine for me.. Thanks a lot.. Am still checking more.. really it was helpful..

Comment: I warned you, the query won't work when there is no data for BOTH dates, just try changing the year to 2016... :)

Comment: @FutbolFan yes, you're right. But if there is no row for BOTH dates, for me wouldn't work

Comment: @Shine I am a bit confused, how would database return rows if there is no data in both queries?

Comment: for example SELECT COUNT() WHERE unexisting_rows_clause ALWAYS returns (0, in this case). You should return 0 even with no rows on the entire DB if I understood the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a conditional aggregate:

```
SELECT  NVL(Last_Week_Collected, 0) AS Last_Week_Collected,
        NVL(THIS_Week_Collected, 0) AS THIS_Week_Collected,
        NVL(Last_Week_Errored, 0) AS Last_Week_Errored,
        NVL(THIS_Week_Errored, 0) AS THIS_Week_Errored,
        NVL(Last_Week_Processed, 0) AS Last_Week_Processed,
        NVL(THIS_Week_Processed, 0) AS THIS_Week_Processed
FROM    
(   SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(batch_Creation_date,'DD-MON-YY')= '27-08-2015' THEN collected ELSE 0 END) AS Last_Week_Collected,    
            MAX(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(batch_Creation_date,'DD-MON-YY')= '03-09-2015' THEN collected ELSE 0 END) AS THIS_Week_Collected,   
            MAX(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(batch_Creation_date,'DD-MON-YY')= '27-08-2015' THEN errored ELSE 0 END) AS Last_Week_Errored,   
            MAX(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(batch_Creation_date,'DD-MON-YY')= '03-09-2015' THEN errored ELSE 0 END) AS THIS_Week_Errored,   
            MAX(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(batch_Creation_date,'DD-MON-YY')= '27-08-2015' THEN processed ELSE 0 END) AS Last_Week_Processed,   
            MAX(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(batch_Creation_date,'DD-MON-YY')= '03-09-2015' THEN processed ELSE 0 END) AS THIS_Week_Processed   
    FROM    processing_Stats_Archive 
    WHERE   stream_id = '29'  
    AND     HR_OF_DAY ='5'   
    AND     TO_CHAR(batch_Creation_date,'DD-MON-YY') IN ('27-08-2015', '03-09-2015')
) t;
```

Your current query would only work if there was one row per week, so I have assumed this to be the case. Therefore although I have applied the `MAX` function, it is pretty meaningless because it is the `MAX` of one row.

This is a scalar aggregate, that is to say it has an aggregate function and no group by, it will always return one row, regardless of whether or not there is data.

Comment: If there was no rows for specified dates you wouldn't retrieve nothing

Comment: @Shine - `wouldn't retrieve nothing`??

Comment: Yes, I think your answer is wrong. If on DB there is no row for both dates, you would select no row and your CASEs wouldn't get even executed

Comment: @Shine, yes you would. It is a scalar aggregate as oppose to a vector aggregate. A scalar aggregate always returns one row. I did take the time to explain this in the answer, but if you don't believe my explanation. Maybe seeing is believing, so I put together an [SQL Fiddle to demonstrate a row being returned with no data at all in the table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b36da/3)

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but on the fiddle you are not returning anything [NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL] while you should return [0,0,0,0,0,0]

Comment: [null,null,null,null,null,null,null] is  still a row, it may require some slight tweaking to make it show 0 instead of null, but this is purely aesthetic. [Example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b36da/15), the point remains though, that if you use an aggregate with no group by it will always return 1 row.

Comment: your updated answer is correct and way better than mine for both readability and performance :)

Answer (score 0):

may be u want this output

```
   SELECT COALESCE(b.collected,0) AS Last_Week_Collected
,a.collected AS THIS_Week_Collected
,COALESCE(b.errored,0) AS   Last_Week_Errored   
,a.errored AS THIS_Week_Errored   
,COALESCE(b.processed,0) AS Last_Week_Processed
,a.processed AS   THIS_Week_Processed 
FROM   
(
SELECT stream_id,collected,errored ,processed 
FROM processing_Stats_Archive
WHERE stream_id = '29'  AND HR_OF_DAY ='5' 
AND TO_CHAR(batch_Creation_date,'DD-MON-YY')= '03-09-2015'  
)a LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT stream_id,collected,errored ,processed  
FROM processing_Stats_Archive 
WHERE stream_id = '29'  AND HR_OF_DAY ='5' AND TO_CHAR(batch_Creation_date,'DD-MON-YY')= '27-08-2015'  
) 
b ON a.stream_id=b.stream_id
```

Comment: @user2642751 then replace inner join with left join ..i have update my ans..look it

Comment: a left join is not enought if there are no rows with stream_id = '29'  AND HR_OF_DAY ='5'  in processing_Stats_Archive Table

Comment: @Shine  I think even if  second query from  have no records then still rows returns from first query due to left join.. isn't correct??

Comment: @Raj yes it's correct. But what about "left part"? I mean, if query a is returning no row (for date '03-09-2015') you don't have nothing to join :)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that **no type of JOIN or aggregate functions (like MAX) will help you if there's nothing to join or to aggregate**. You should work with separate queries to retrieve single "collected", "errored" and "processed" columns AND coalesce them to 0. I used `NVL` in my answer here, thinking you're using Oracle DBMS

Try with this:

```
SELECT (
        NVL(SELECT collected
            FROM processing_Stats_Archive 
            WHERE stream_id = '29'  
            AND HR_OF_DAY ='5'  
            AND TO_CHAR(batch_Creation_date,'DD-MON-YY') =  '03-09-2015' ,0)
        AS THIS_Week_Errored, 
            NVL(SELECT errored
            FROM processing_Stats_Archive 
            WHERE stream_id = '29'  
            AND HR_OF_DAY ='5'  
            AND TO_CHAR(batch_Creation_date,'DD-MON-YY') =  '03-09-2015' ,0) 
        AS THIS_Week_Errored,
            NVL (SELECT processed
            FROM processing_Stats_Archive 
            WHERE stream_id = '29'  
            AND HR_OF_DAY ='5'  
            AND TO_CHAR(batch_Creation_date,'DD-MON-YY') =  '03-09-2015' ,0) 
        AS THIS_Week_Processed ) 
        UNION
        NVL(SELECT collected
            FROM processing_Stats_Archive 
            WHERE stream_id = '29'  
            AND HR_OF_DAY ='5'  
            AND TO_CHAR(batch_Creation_date,'DD-MON-YY') =  '27-08-2015' ,0)
        AS Last_Week_Collected, 
            NVL(SELECT errored
            FROM processing_Stats_Archive 
            WHERE stream_id = '29'  
            AND HR_OF_DAY ='5'  
            AND TO_CHAR(batch_Creation_date,'DD-MON-YY') =  '27-08-2015' ,0) 
        AS Last_Week_Errored,
            NVL (SELECT processed
            FROM processing_Stats_Archive 
            WHERE stream_id = '29'  
            AND HR_OF_DAY ='5'  
            AND TO_CHAR(batch_Creation_date,'DD-MON-YY') =  '27-08-2015' ,0) 
        AS Last_Week_Processed )
    FROM DUAL
```

Comment: This probably works, but is a pretty poor solution, you are reading from the same table 6 times when you could do it in a single read.

Comment: I agree, it is a poor solution